# POO en PHP - Creación de objetos

Tags: php, poo

¿Es correcta esta forma de crear objetos y su acceso inmediato en php?

```
foreach($settlements as $settlement){ 
    $settlement->txs = new CredoraxTransaction()->getUnsettledTxNew($settlement->currency);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si esta bien, pero dificulta un poco la lectura, utilízalo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($settlements as $settlement){ 
  $settlement->txs = new CredoraxTransaction()
                        ->getUnsettledTxNew($settlement->currency);
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que este tipo de ejecuciones requieren versiones de PHP no muy antiguas, así como las que no permiten extraer un arreglo directamente de una función

Comment: Puedes seguir estas normas : https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

Answer (score 0):

No es correcta. Al ejecutar varias lineas de ese tipo de va a salir error.

La forma correcta es esta:

```
foreach($settlements as $settlement){ 
    $currency = $settlement->currency;
    $settlement = new CredoraxTransaction();
    $setelement = $settlement->getUnsettledTxNew($currency);
    $settlement->txs;
}
```

Aunque son unas lineas de código de más, es una forma más ordenada y evitando errores.

Comment: Por qué debería salir error? , el intérprete al generar el arbol expandirá creando las variables que necesite, no es necesario, ni tampoco dará error, eso sin mencionar del daño de crear variables, un programador promedio sólo puede retener el significado de 4 variables, en este caso ya ocupas 3, dificultando la comprensión del código.

Answer (score 0):

Sintácticamente está bien, y funciona, pero 
dificulta la readibilidad del código, por violar [la ley de Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

La forma correcta sería refactorizar el código, creando funciones que traigan un acceso más rapido del elemento CreadoraxTransaction

```
...
function get_unsettled_tx_for($element){
    $ctrans = new CreadoraxTransaction();
    return $ctrans -> getUnsettledTxNew ($element -> currency);
}
...
foreach($settlements as $settlement){ 
    $settelement -> txs = get_unsettled_txt_for ($settelement)
}
```

Comment: Se podría encerrar en `()` _...acceso a miembro de clase en la instanciación..._   [desde PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)... no? Ejemplo: `$settlement->txs = ( new CredoraxTransaction() )->getUnsettledTxNew($settlement->currency);`

Comment: Sí, pero si necesitas utilizar otro método sobre el mismo objeto creado, no tendrías la referencia al objeto, es algo debitable, si consideras que vas utilizar el objeto en algún momento, entonces creas la variable, de lo contrario no, y lo dejas tal cual `$settlement->txs = ( new CredoraxTransaction() )->getUnsettledTxNew($settlement->currency);`